# How to list all paths through graph using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginning Haskeller. This is a script I thought would take a few minutes to build, but it's caused me quite a bit of difficulty.

Say we have a graph composed of nodes and edges. The data structure is a list of node-to-node pairs, like this:

```
[(1,6),(1,8),(6,9),(6,10),(6,13),(8,13)]
```

[image: Graphical Representation]

I want to build a function that walks through the graph and shows all possible paths from a starting node to all reachable nodes at the bottom.

So a couple ideal executions of the function might look like this:

```
> allPaths 1 [(1,6),(1,8),(6,9),(6,10),(6,13),(8,13)]
[[1,6,9],[1,6,10],[1,6,13],[1,8,13]]
> allPaths 8 [(1,6),(1,8),(6,9),(6,10),(6,13),(8,13)]
[[8,13]]
```

Here's my initial attempt which just starts to build the list of paths:

```
allPaths start graph = [start : [snd edge] | edge <- graph, fst edge == start]

> allPaths 8 [(1,6),(1,8),(6,9),(6,10),(6,13),(8,13)]
[[1,6],[1,8]]
```

The problem is I don't know how to make this solution use recursion to finish the paths. This is one of several lame attempts which doesn't pass a type check:

```
allPaths start graph = [start : (snd edge : allPaths (snd edge) graph) | edge <- graph, fst edge == start]

    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    Expected type: [a]
      Actual type: [[a]]
    Relevant bindings include
      edge :: (a, a) (bound at allpaths.hs:5:72)
      graph :: [(a, a)] (bound at allpaths.hs:5:16)
      start :: a (bound at allpaths.hs:5:10)
      allPaths :: a -> [(a, a)] -> [[a]]
        (bound at allpaths.hs:5:1)
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `allPaths (snd edge) graph'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely
      `(snd edge : allPaths (snd edge) graph)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What does this mean? Is my list nesting going too deep.

Does anyone have a solution or a better approach?

Comment: A node in a tree can only have one parent. This is a graph, not a tree.

Comment: Would it make more sense to convert your list of edges to an actual tree structure?  It'd certainly make it easier to recurse on.

Comment: @VincentSavard: Thank you. Have changed references from "tree" to "graph"

Comment: @bheklilr: This data structure happened to be the easiest to build, and I thought it would work. But yes, maybe I need to switch to a different structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
allPaths :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> [[Int]]
allPaths start graph = nextLists
    where
      curNodes = filter (\(f,_) -> f == start) graph
      nextStarts = map snd curNodes
      nextLists = if curNodes == []
                  then [[start]]
                  else map ((:) start) $ concat $ map (\nextStart -> allPaths nextStart graph) nextStarts
```

In practice:

```
*Main> allPaths 1 [(1,6),(1,8),(6,9),(6,10),(6,13),(8,13)]
[[1,6,9],[1,6,10],[1,6,13],[1,8,13]]
*Main> allPaths 8 [(1,6),(1,8),(6,9),(6,10),(6,13),(8,13)]
[[8,13]]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you switch to a different representation of a graph this becomes much easier.  The structure I'm using here is not necessarily the best or most efficient, and I'm not doing any checking against cyclic relationships, but it is simpler to work with than lists of edges.

First, some imports

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
```

The structure we have is a relationship between an `Int` node label and its child nodes, so

```
type Node = Int
type Children = [Node]
type Graph = M.Map Node Children
```

Now we can write down our test graph:

```
testGraph :: Graph
testGraph = M.fromList
    [ (1,  [6, 8])
    , (6,  [9, 10, 13])
    , (8,  [13])
    , (9,  [])
    , (10, [])
    , (13, [])
    ]
```

To make this even simpler, you can write a function to go from your list of edges to this structure pretty easily:

```
fromEdges :: [(Node, Node)] -> Graph
fromEdges = M.fromListWith (++) . map (fmap (:[]))
```

(This does not add them in the same order, you could use a `Data.Set.Set` mitigate this issue.)

Now you simply have

```
testGraph = fromEdges [(1,6),(1,8),(6,9),(6,10),(6,13),(8,13)]
```

For implementing the function `allPaths :: Node -> Graph -> [[Node]]` things are now pretty straightforward.  We have only three cases to consider:

1. When looking up a node in the graph, the node does not exist.  Should return the empty list.
2. The node exists in the graph, but has no children.  Should return the paths `[[node]]`.
3. The node exists in the graph and has children.  Should return all paths of all children prepended with the current node.

So

```
allPaths startingNode graph =
    case M.lookup startingNode graph of
        Nothing -> []                -- Case 1
        Just [] -> [[startingNode]]  -- Case 2
        Just kids ->                 -- Case 3
            map (startingNode:) $    -- All paths prepended with current node
                concatMap (`allPaths` graph) kids  -- All kids paths
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs in the recursive call to `allPaths`.

A shorter example of failing to construct an *infinite type* is: `f x = [f x]`.

Here, the return type of `f` must be list of whatever `f` returns. The same goes for `allPaths`.

This problem can typically be solved with a single call to `concat`. In your case, since you use list comprehensions instead of list combinators, this corresponds to unpacking the result from your recursive call:

```
allPaths :: Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
allPaths startNode graph = map (startNode:) (go startNode)
  where
    go curNode =
      case [ snd node | node <- graph, fst node == curNode ] of
        [] -> [[]]
        nextNodes -> [ nextNode : path | nextNode <- nextNodes, path <- go nextNode ]
```

Here, `path <- go nextNode` covers the `concatMap` you're missing.

Comment: @Simon, your code works nicely but results in an error "Not in scope: 'start'" as written. I believe you mean for the two "start" references to read "startNode". ie: allPaths startNode graph = map (startNode:) (go startNode).

Answer (score 1):

WolfeFan has given a good approach above for finding all paths in a graph. But it goes in infinite loop when there is a cycle in the graph. I am just modifying his code a bit so that it can also give cyclic path if there is any.

```
allPaths :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]->[Int] -> [[Int]]
allPaths start graph visited = nextLists
    where
         curNodes = filter (\(f,_) -> f == start) graph
         nextStarts = map snd curNodes
         nextLists |any (\x-> x `elem` visited) nextStarts = [[start]] -- Responsible for prinitng cyclic paths
                   |otherwise = if curNodes == []
                         then [[start]] -- Responsible for printing non-cyclic paths
                                else map ((:) start) $ concat $ map (\nextStart -> allPaths nextStart graph (start:visited)) nextStarts
```

In Practice:
*Main> allPaths 1 [(1,6),(1,8),(6,9),(6,10),(6,13),(8,13),(9,8),(8,1)] []

[[1,6,9,8],[1,6,10],[1,6,13],[1,8]]